# How to replace a webfile content with a file content?

Tags: php

I have a file called **filecontent.txt** which includes some php code.

And i have another file called **index.php**,

I want to **replace** the **index.php** content with the **filecontent.txt** content.

Is there any solution for it??

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php copy function

eg:

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

[PHP COPY](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Comment: Whats is the result and what's excepted ?

Answer (score 0):

You may also [delete](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) the index.php and [rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) the filecontent.txt to index.php afterwards, if its just a replacement.

Comment: do i need to delete beforehand or does php override without complaining?

Comment: That hasn't to do with PHP, but with the underlying file-system. In general, you can't rename an file to a name thats already given to another file—so yes, you need to delete it first.

Comment: I just want to replace full contents includeing the php tags.
I don't want to do this for a single file,i have many files

Answer (score 0):

```
unlink ("index.php");
rename ("filecontent.txt", "index.php");
```